# is_front_page() not working

Tags: javascript, homepage

I'm trying to load a script from `functions.php` just when I'm on the front page. I set a static page called "home" in the reading options.

The home page loads the `front-page.php` template correctly but the conditional script loading doesn't work.

This is what I have in my `functions.php` file:

```
wp_register_script('nivoslider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/libs/nivoslider.js', false, false, true);

if (is_front_page()) {   
   wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider'); 
}
```

Why isn't this loading as expected? What's happening here?

This is my `init_scripts` function:

```
function init_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        /* Modernizr
         */
        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/libs/modernizr.js');

        /* jQuery
        */
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false, false, true);

        /* Nivo Slider 
        */
        wp_register_script('nivoslider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/libs/nivoslider.js', false, false, true);

        /* Custom scripts
         */
        wp_register_script('plugins', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/plugins.js', false, false, true);
        wp_register_script('script', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/script.js',false, false, true);

        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr');       
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('plugins');
        wp_enqueue_script('script');

        if (is_front_page()) {   
            wp_enqueue_script('nivoslider'); 
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_scripts');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this directly in `functions.php` you are doing it wrong. It is too early for conditional tags to work.

This should be hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, see [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) docs.

Comment: I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong. I updated the question with my functions.php init_scripts function. All my other scripts load just fine.

Comment: @elclanrs...your updated code looks good. I'm guessing Rarst thought you were not wrapping the code in a function that was called with a hook.

Comment: Still doesn't work with the code posted above...

Comment: @elclanrs as per my answer this needs to be hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `init`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `is_home()` instead of `is_front_page`. There is a subtle difference between the two (http://nspeaks.com/1069/difference-between-is_home-and-is_front_page/), which might account for your difficulties.

Comment: Nop. `is_home()` is for the blog posts home page if I understand correctly. `is_front_page()` should work but it doesn't. And `is_page('Home')` doesn't work either...

Comment: Can you do `var_dump(is_front_page())` to see if the variable is correct? You may even want to do `global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query);` to further explore if there is something unusual occurring with the query vars.

Comment: It returns FALSE, wtf! I don't get it!

Comment: Should i try re-installing WP?

Comment: No...that's unnecessary. Can you show me what `global $wp_query; echo '<pre>'; var_dump($wp_query); echo '</pre>';` prints out? Perhaps do a pastebin or add it to the original question.

Comment: Ok, here http://pastebin.com/1R8Nrdyq. Thanks for your time. I'm quite new to WP so I might be missing something.

Comment: Btw, `is_page()` returns FALSE too. I'm definitely doing something wrong because it is a page; it has the page class on the body tag. And according to the dump it says that `is_home() == true` but it doesn't load the plugin...

Comment: Ok...try this pastebin...does it print "is_home"? If so, then the problem is likely with your JS.