# is_front_page not working at all in any of the themes .php files

Tags: conditional-tags

I am using the Paragrams theme from the kind folks at wpshower. I have a little different front page that I would like to load with an image rotator and different layout in the for loop. I have tried all of the conditional comments, with no avail.

There are some posts on this already that didn't have a solution...

- [is_front_page, is_page('slug'), is_page(id) not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33268/is-front-page-is-pageslug-is-pageid-not-working)
- [is_front_page() not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/is-front-page-not-working-wordpress)

I even tried this most basic if else from the WP forum without any help. What am i missing? :(

```
<?php
if (is_front_page())
{?>

<div>Flash Gordon</div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div>Wins the Battle!</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a page template? Make a copy of page.php and call it page-home.php (if your home page is an actual page in Wordpress with the name of 'Home') or if not, then create a file called front-page.php and Wordpress will use that as the homepage template.

These two Wordpress Codex links will help you:

- [Page templates for pages via ID or slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Templates_by_page-ID_or_page-Slug)
- [Wordpress front page display templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display)

Comment: Thanks Dwayne. That was the ticket. front-page.php that is...

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked for you Buildakicker. By the way, welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks! I just found that StackOverflow had all these other sites! LOVE IT! I use WP and SharePoint quite a bit, so this is so nice.